# This is my laravel query and I have get result but very slow can help me for how to good way or improve this query ...I want only 10 record

Tags: laravel, optimization

```php
$CompanySaftyCheckReport = CompanySaftyCheckReport:: join('company_safty_checks','company_safty_checks.id','=','company_safty_check_reports.company_safty_check_id')
                        ->join('company_safty_check_report_apps','company_safty_check_reports.company_safty_check_report_app_id','=','company_safty_check_report_apps.id')
                        ->join('company_safty_check_report_vehicles', 'company_safty_check_report_vehicles.company_safty_check_report_app_id', '=', 'company_safty_check_report_apps.id')
                        ->join('users','users.id','=','company_safty_check_report_apps.user_id')
                        ->join('vehicles', 'vehicles.id', '=', 'company_safty_check_report_vehicles.vehicle_id')
                        ->where('company_safty_checks.type','v')
                        ->select('company_safty_check_reports.*','company_safty_checks.title','company_safty_checks.type','users.first_name','users.last_name','company_safty_check_report_apps.id as userId','company_safty_check_report_apps.signature','company_safty_check_report_vehicles.vehicle_id', 'vehicles.vehicle_rego', 'company_safty_check_report_apps.created_at as app_date', 'company_safty_check_report_apps.time_to_complete', 'company_safty_check_report_apps.time_commenced')
                        ->where('company_safty_check_report_apps.company_id',Auth::user()->company_id)
                        ->groupBy('company_safty_check_report_vehicles.company_safty_check_report_app_id')
                        ->orderBy('company_safty_check_report_apps.created_at', 'desc')
                        ->take(10)
                        ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Make use of the laravel relationships.
If you are using MySql database try indexing the columns, that are using for joining the tables as well in the where condition. Please refer below mentioned links

[How to create index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388058/how-to-create-index)

[Sql Indexes](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_index.asp)

[Laravel Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Since the database structure are not provided with the question, Im using hasMany relationship for all.
Kindly update with your own requirement or you own database structure

```
CompanySaftyCheckReport::with(['SafteyChecks',
                               'SafteyCheckApps',
                               'SafteyCheckApps.ReportVehicles',
                               'SafteyCheckApps.ReportVehicles.vehicles',
                               'users'])
                      ->where(function(Builder $query1){
                            return $query1->whereHas('SafteyChecks',fn(Builder $query2)=>$query2->where('type','v'))
                                          ->whereHas('SafteyCheckApps',fn(Builder $query3)=>$query3->where('company_id',Auth::user()->company_id));
                        })
                      ->groupBy('SafteyCheckApps.ReportVehicles.company_safty_check_report_app_id')
                      ->orderBy('SafteyCheckApps.created_at', 'desc')
                      ->take(10)->get();
```

---

### --------------- CompanySaftyCheckReport Model ---------------

```
public function SafteyChecks(){
return $this->hasMany(CompanySaftyChecksModel::class,'id','company_safty_check_id');
}

public function SafteyCheckApps(){
return $this->hasMany(CompanySaftyCheckReportAppsModel::class,'id','company_safty_check_report_app_id');
}

public function users(){
return $this->hasMany(UsersModel::class,'id','user_id');
}
```

---

### ---------- CompanySaftyCheckReportAppsModel Model  ----------

```
public function ReportVehicles(){
return $this->hasMany(CompanySaftyCheckReportVehiclesModel::class,'company_safty_check_report_app_id','company_safty_check_report_app_id');
}
```

---

### ---------- CompanySaftyCheckReportVehiclesModel Model  ----------

```
public function vehicles(){
return $this->hasMany(VehiclesModel::class,'vehicle_id','id');
}
```