# How to create indexes with conditions in Oracle 12c?

Tags: oracle, indexing, database-migration

I want to migrate a PostgreSQL database into Oracle 12c, and for example in the table creation below, I've found some difficults:

- How to (if possible) to create these unique indexes with **where** clause?
- How to properly add this primary key pessoa_id?
- Why I get this error 'missing right parenthesis'?

Code:

```
create table nano.pessoa (
    id              GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY,
    nome            varchar(99) not null, 
    sobrenome       varchar(99) not null, 
    nascimento_dt   date,
    registro        varchar(32) not null,   
    fisica_sn       bool default true,   -- no caso de pf, true, pf, falso
    matriz_sn       bool default false,  -- no caso de pf, é o genero, masculino = true
    confirmado_sn   bool default false,
    constraint pessoa_id primary key(id)
);  

create unique index pessoa_juridica_cnpj_ix on pessoas.pessoa (registro) where (fisica_sn = false);
create unique index pessoa_fisica_ix on pessoas.pessoa (nome, sobrenome, nascimento_dt) where (fisica_sn = true);
create unique index pessoa_fisica_cpf_ix on pessoas.pessoa (registro) where ((fisica_sn = true) and ((registro <> null) and (registro <> '')));
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939776/does-oracle-have-a-filtered-index-concept#5940209

Answer (score 7):

there is no conditional index in Oracle DB, you can convert the logic to be function based indexes.

so the following :

```
create unique index pessoa_juridica_cnpj_ix on pessoa (registro) where (fisica_sn = false);
```

becomes in Oracle SQL :

```
create unique index pessoa_juridica_cnpj_ix on pessoa (case when fisica_sn = false then registro end) ;
```

Comment: `fisica_sn = false` instead of `fisica_sn is null`