# Unique constraint where only one row can be 'Yes' (but based on values in other columns)

Tags: oracle, unique-constraint

I have a database for storing logo images. There can be several different types of logo images. There are also multiple systems which isolate these logos from each other.

The rule is that there can only be one **active** logo of each **type** in each **system**.

I'm trying to make a constraint for this. Here's what I have right now:

```
alter table logo_t
add constraint logo_active_uk
unique (
  SystemId,
  LogoType,
  Active
) using index tablespace t_indexes;
```

This is close, but the problem is that it only allows one logo to be **inactive** at any time. So basically, I need to ignore any inactive logos (`active = 'No'`) in the constraint.

It seems like this should be possible, but I'm not really sure how to fix this.

Comment: In SQL Server, I'd use a filtered unique index. https://stackoverflow.com/q/5939776/121544 is an SO question about Oracle equivalent to filtered indexes. Might be you could adapt to filtered unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
create unique index logo_active_uk
on logo_t(
  (case when Active = 'Yes' then SystemId || LogoType || Active else null end)
) tablespace t_indexes;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think if there is any column storing inactive date/time, Just add that column in your script. That will make all your records unique and will solve your purpose. So just update your script as -

```
alter table logo_t
add constraint logo_active_uk
unique (
  SystemId,
  LogoType,
  Active,
  <Your_time/timestamp_column> 
) using index tablespace t_indexes;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any other columns (such as a timestamp) to make the rows unique. That is a really clever solution though!